# ActionScript 3 Dynamically changing text called from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am trying to dynamically change the text in a text box located in a class.
So here is my Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.text.engine.TextBlock;
    import flash.text.engine.TextElement;
    import flash.text.engine.TextLine;
    import flash.text.engine.ElementFormat;
    import flash.text.engine.FontDescription;
    import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip

    public class textClass extends MovieClip
    {
        public var te:TextElement;
        public var ef:ElementFormat;
        public var fd:FontDescription = new FontDescription();
        public var str:String;
        public var tl:TextLine;
        public var tb:TextBlock = new TextBlock();

        public function textClass()
        {
            fd.fontName = "Sketch Rockwell";
            ef = new ElementFormat(fd);
            ef.fontSize = 40;
            ef.color = 0x000000;

            str = "This is the text I want to change";
            te = new TextElement(str,ef);
            tb.content = te;
            var color:Number = 0xFFFFFF;
            var angle:Number = 0;
            var alpha1:Number = 1;
            var blurX:Number = 3;
            var blurY:Number = 3;
            var distance:Number = 0;
            var strength:Number = 64;
            var inner:Boolean = false;
            var knockout:Boolean = false;
            var quality:Number = 3;
            var stroke:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(
               distance,
               angle,
               color,
               alpha1,
               blurX,
               blurY,
               strength,
               quality,
               inner,
               knockout);
            tl = tb.createTextLine(null,1395);
            addChild(tl);
            tl.x = 54;
            tl.y = 674;
            tl.filters = [stroke];

        }

    }

}
```

And this is how I called the class in the main timeline:

```
var myText:textClass = new textClass();
this.addChild(myText);
```

The text displays perfectly but I cannot figure out how to dynamically change the text from the main timeline.
I tried using replaceText(), but I received an error telling me replaceText() was an undefined method and that my text field is static. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried doing this as well...

    var myText:textClass = new textClass();
    this.addChild(myText);
    trace(this.str);
    this.str = "new";
    trace(this.str);
    this.removeChild(myText);
    this.addChild(myText); 

The trace shows that the variable changes to "new" but the Text displayed by the class does not change.

Comment: Why are you trying access it by `this.str = "new";`, then it should be `myText.str="new";`?

Comment: I tried myText.str="new"; in the code. basically it works exactly the same as this.str = "new"; because they refer to the same class. That is nice to know but it doesn't change the text. :(

Comment: I'm starting to think the reason it isn't allowing me to change the text is because the text line I am writing to is static. I'll do some google searches when I get back from work and figure it out.

Comment: You should try `myText.str="new"`; not inside you class definition but there you create new instance of you class. Inside of definition `this` refers to class instance, inside timeline to timeline instance

Comment: You need to call `replaceText` on the `TextElement` instance, in your case `te`. Since `te` is public, you should be able to do `myText.te.replaceText(...)`

Comment: I used myText.te.replaceText(0, 0, "new") the text did not change at all. :( It compiled fine though at least.

Comment: Something New I just Tried. te.replaceText(0, 0, "A text fragment: ");  inside the class before: tl = tb.createTextLine(null,1395); and it will change the text. If I place replaceText anywhere after that it won't allow me to change the text.... what??

Comment: can't figure it out. Tried a lot of different things. Got so frustrated. oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the implementation, it's hard to say how you're doing it wrong.  I can say, the only place you should be running replaceText() is on your [TextElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/engine/TextElement.html#replaceText%28%29).

```
var myText:textClass = new textClass();
this.addChild(myText);
te.replaceText(0, 0, "foo");
```

If I were you, I'd just use [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) as all of these properties/methods are set up there for you.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Sketch Rockwell";
format.size = "40";
format.color = 0x000000;

var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.defaultTextFormat = format;
txt.text = "Hello World!";
```